# Python snap7 importerror: cannot find module snap7 windows10

Tags: python, module, importerror, snap7

I am new to Python and am trying it for an automation project of mine.
I am trying to use a 64-bit python (version 3.5.3) on windows 10 (64-bit).
I have copied the .dll and .lib files of snap7 for win 64-bit into my Python Path which is added to my system path.I have downloaded the python-snap7 wrapper version 0.8

But despite all this, I am getting an import error: No module named snap7.

I did follow all that was said in the link below too. But nothing seems to work.

[python snap7 windows - can't find snap7 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33697263/python-snap7-windows-cant-find-snap7-library)

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
When I tried installing snap7 using pip..I got this error

```
>>> python -m pip install python-snap7
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python -m pip install python-snap7
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vrinda\Desktop\1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import snap7
ImportError: No module named 'snap7'
```

Solution: I had to install it from Command window..not python interpreter

Comment: Why don't you install it using pip? `pip install python-snap7`

Comment: Could you post stack trace? Which error are you getting?

Comment: Just copy paste it as text and then select it and click on the braces on the question editor. Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named?rq=1 for example.

Comment: Thank you @RaviKumar!..I took some time to figure out some trivial stuff but using pip worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Python from the official Microsoft Store, the pip installer is included. You need just to paste `pip install python-snap7` in the command line, as [Ravi Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223717/python-snap7-importerror-cannot-find-module-snap7-windows10?newreg=9547983647f44b0eba3525cc4ead15e7#comment73517658_43223717) said.

If you are using Visual Studio Code and get the warning, *"Import "[module]" could not be resolvedPylance (reportMissingImports)"*, then just restart VS Code.